# Android GCM - integrating with Urban Airship

Tags: android, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging, urbanairship.com

I have GCM enabled with my django app using the parts of the code from [this app](https://github.com/bogdal/django-gcm).

Everything is working perfectly. However, I would like to also enable `UrbanAirship`, since I'll be doing a lot with scheduled push notifications, which is something I would like to rely on a third party for.

The problem I'm noticing with Urban Airship is that it wants an `apid`. My app already has `device_id` and `registration_id` (GCM id) using GCM. Is there any way to get the `apid` using these two values? Or should I look elsewhere?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

APID is an ID generated by Urban Airship. It has nothing to do with the IDs you already have. When you use their API, you'll get an APID for each device.

> An APID (Airship Push ID) is the unique Urban Airship identifier required in order to push to an Android device via our API. Each new installation of an application generates a new APID, so if you uninstall and then reinstall the app, it will get a new APID for that app.

You can read more about it [here](http://docs.urbanairship.com/connect/android_push.html).